Path suggestions in string
I am using nvim-cmp, for my popup suggestions, the path suggestion activates when I starts to write /home, fortunately this works both in the file opened (in buffer) as well as in command line but the suggestions doesn't work if I am writing in strings (means in between "quotes" for most languages), paths in the form of string is often required in various form of code logic. General text suggestions are provided by LSP and buffer in the string so there might be some way to activate path suggestions in strings too which I am unaware of. I also checked the Advanced techniques but couldn't find anything relevent.
How do I enable path suggestions in strings?

Vim's default way of doing file name completion is Ctrl-XCtrl-F.
This works out of the box, without a plugin.
You will have to trigger it manually, though.
You would use it like this
my_path = "/some/path/to<C-X><C-F>"

And the menu showing the existing paths starting with /some/path/to will pop up.
The related documentation is found in :help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F or start reading about all completion options in :help ins-completion.

few issues in the approach, on testing, the completion only works afterwards the pwd, means not able to suggest absolute paths and only the file and folders from which nvim was started, secondly on entering a sub folder I have to click the keys again for further suggestions, the default suggestions of path in nvim-cmp overcomes both of these issues. Even if I ignore the second one, not being able to suggest abs paths makes it less useful.

@BhaumikTripathi I never encountered any problems when specifying an absolute path. What should be considered part of the path depends on the 'isfname' option, that's one possible point of failure.

Just for reassurance, type /home/{your_username}/ (if you use linux) in a file made in a nested folder and then trigger the completion with the keys, does that show the files and folder to you for the root directory? If yes, then there might be some issue on my end.

Not sure I can follow you here. When I type /home/username/<C-X><C-F> I see the files in my user's directory (Desktop, Documents, etc.). If I wanted to see files in root dir, I'd have to type /<C-X><C-F>.

And I'm totally aware my answer isn't the one you wanted. I was mainly thinking about future readers with a similar problem. You're probably looking for some magic configuration option for your nvim-cmp plugin. It's just I'm completely ignorant of that plugin. Other community members may know it.

Thanks @Friedrich for your time and patience,this seems to me the best solution so far, and also that its working with the roost dirs, but after you type / as you suggested, and this will pretty much resolve the problem I asked the question for, getting suggestions in string, not exactly what I thought but it works descent too.
